# utility of thumbnail class in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add images in my web site, I have successfully displayed them.
I just saw some examples tagging thumbnail class and I didn't understand what does it do.

```
<div class="thumbnail">
```

knowing that I tried my own code without thumbnail class and then I tried by using that class and the result was the same in both.

```
<div class="contrainer">                    
  <div class="row">        
      <div class="col-md-6">    
        <img src="enseignant.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">  
        <img src="etu.jpg">
      </div>
  </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: Are you referring to [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/#image-thumbnails) Bootstrap class? If so: the documentation there explains what it does.

Comment: check out [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/#image-thumbnails)

Comment: @Mathyn i'm talking about      <div class="thumbnail"> not     <div class="img-thumbnail">

Comment: @kukkuz i'm talking about <div class="thumbnail"> not <div class="img-thumbnail">

Comment: @titi A quick search of Bootstrap 4's CSS shows no `.thumbnail` class anywhere, so it's not shocking that it has no effect. Bootstrap **3** had a `.thumbnail` class.

Comment: @titi - the `thumbnail` class that was used in Bootstrap 3, **doesn't exist in Bootstrap 4**. That's why you need to **[read the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/#components)**.

Comment: @ceejayoz ah I see, thnx

Comment: alright  thank u @Zim